# Rにおける関数の代入のmatch.arg(method)でのエラーについて

Tags: r

RMeCabFreq()を用いて形態素解析した結果から、
以下のように関数を用いてデータクレンジングしようと試みているのですが、
filter()を用いた関数を定義し、それを実行しようとすると
予期せぬエラーが発生してしまい、困っています。

エラー文でいろいろと調べてみたのですが、
私と同じようなエラーが発生している事例は発見できず…。

ご助言をいただければ幸いです。

**データ**（データ名：kuchikomi1.txt、文字コードはANSI）
また大容量が出て欲しいです、、、！(*^^*)

**コード**

```
#作業ディレクトリの指定、---、-----は伏字
setwd("C:/Users/---/OneDrive/R/-----")

#必要になるライブラリの読み込み
library("RMeCab")
library("stringr")

#名詞、形容詞、動詞、副詞の抽出
result0 <- RMeCabFreq("kuchikomi1.txt") 
result1 <- subset(result0, result0$Info1 == "名詞"|result0$Info1 == "形容詞"|result0$Info1 == "動詞"|result0$Info1 == "副詞")

#不要な情報を除去するための関数の定義
trush_delete <- function (x) {
  x <- filter(x, (Info1 == "名詞"|Info1 == "形容詞"|Info1 == "動詞"|Info1 == "副詞"),
                 str_detect(x$Term, '[:punct:]') == 'FALSE',
                 str_detect(x$Term, '[A-z0-9]') == 'FALSE',
                 str_detect(x$Term, '[Α-ω]') == 'FALSE',
                 str_detect(x$Term, '[А-я]') == 'FALSE'
  )
}

#形態素解析した結果に対して関数の実行
result <- trush_delete(result1)
```

**表示されるエラー**

```
 match.arg(method) でエラー: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

この"match.arg(method)"というものがいまいちよくわからず…。
その点も説明していただけると大変嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` 関数の使い方を間違えています. まず, `Info1` というオブジェクトを参照していますが提示されたコード中にはそのようなオブジェクトはありません. おそらく `dplyr` パッケージの `filter()` と混同して, `x` 内の `Info1` 列にアクセスしたいという意図でしょうから, 事前に

```
require(dplyr)
```

で `dplyr` を読み込めば少なくとも同様のエラーが発生しなくなります(もちろんこのパッケージをインストールしている前提です)

また, そうなると `x$term` の `x$` の部分も不要になります (このケースでは結果は変わらないと思います)

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただいたサイトをよく見たら、`dplyr`を使用する旨がきちんと記述されていました…コード内に記載がなかったため、見落としてしまっていたようです。